# iOS Crashlytics not logged in firebase dashboard

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have configured it for firebase in app delegate.
Change *Debug Information Format* to DWARF with dSYM
I write the necessary run scripts.

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

But test crashes not showing in crashlytics dashboard

Finally, when I run `Crashlytics/run` manually, it gives an Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment error, but `GoogleService-Info.plist` is attached to the project and I’m sure. I deleted the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and added it again. Could it be related to
Could you please tell me why or idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very silly problem.I solved my problem. After you build with Xcode, you have to stop xcode and open the app manually.

Comment: The problem is caused by running the app in `Debug` mode. You can easily edit the scheme to run in `Release` mode.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's "GoogleService-Info.plist" problem
because it's the only file that has GOOGLE_APP_ID property.

first, check google plist path. put it under your project folder, and then update your script with a specific path of file:

Xcode path: build phases -> Run Script

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/[project folder name]/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios
```

second: make sure Xcode used your script succeesfully. to check that navigate to:

Xcode path : report navigator

then select a recent ended build and from center log scroll to the end and find this:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE6Ku.png)

as you see in image the validation should be succesfull

- if you didn't find any related log to shell in the build log make sure you unchecked this
  [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j009x.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it didn't solve my problem but it changed my perspective. Script succeeds in report navigator but still doesn't show my test crashes in crashlytics. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XX3W.png

Comment: your welcome, in the next step, check if the panel recognized your user, after installation close the app and open it again, and check this path in the image, set the 3 filters to make sure it's your user if you have multiple versions. you should see the active user in the last 30 minutes.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJrBT.png)

Comment: @Emirhanacısu and check if you have any missing dSYMs (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJrBT.png)

Comment: Showing my user in dashboard. I write Firebase support team, I'll let you know when it's resolved.

Comment: nice, and it would be good to post your solution here too. I hope it solves fast

Answer (score 0):

Script succeeds in report navigator but still doesn't show my test crashes in crashlytics. [imageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XX3W.png)

And I followed these steps of firebase

1. In Xcode, select Product > Scheme > Edit scheme.
2. Select Run from the left menu, then select the Arguments tab.
3. In the Arguments Passed on Launch section, add -FIRDebugEnabled.

But *Completed report submission* did not print logs

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a most important step mentioned in the documentation

While testing for crash please build and detach the Xcode's debugger using square button right before the run button in Xcode

Please refer to this part in documentation
[image]